# Getting data from index.html and sending to main.js is not working with Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to create a rich presence script for discord using JS and HTML (electron obviously). I have created the actual script itself, but I run into this error when clicking on a button inside of the HTML does not actually send the data to the main.js file (using ipc asynchronomous events). Here is the snippet of my index.html:

```
    <script>
        window.onload=function(){

            document.querySelector('#set').addEventListener('click', function() {

            let stateVar = document.getElementById("state").value;
            let detailsVar = document.getElementById("details").value;
            let largeVar = document.getElementById("large").value;
            let smallVar = document.getElementById("small").value;
            let btnUrl1Var = document.getElementById("buttonurl1").value;
            let btnUrl2Var = document.getElementById("buttonurl2").value;
            let btnTxt1Var = document.getElementById("buttontxt1").value;
            let btnTxt2Var = document.getElementById("buttontxt2").value;

            const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');

            // send username to main.js 
            ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', stateVar, detailsVar, largeVar, smallVar, btnUrl1Var, btnUrl2Var, btnTxt1Var, btnTxt2Var );

            // receive message from main.js
            ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', (event, arg) => {
            console.log(arg) 

            })

            });
        }
    </script>
```

and here is a snippet of my main.js:

```
// receive message from index.html 
ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
    console.log( arg );
  
    // send message to index.html
    event.sender.send('asynchronous-reply', 'hello' );

    const activity={
        state: stateVar,
        details: detailsVar,
        assets:{
            large_image: "paimon",
            large_text: largeVar,
            small_image: "xiaoresized",
            small_text: smallVar,
        },
        buttons:[
            {
                "label": btnTxt1Var,
                "url": btnUrl1Var
                },
            {
                "label": btnTxt2Var,
                "url": btnUrl2Var
            }
        ],
        timestamps: {start: Date.now()},
        instance: true
    };
            
    client.on("ready", () => {
        client.request("SET_ACTIVITY", {pid: process.pid, activity: activity});
        console.log("will this work");
    
    })
    
    client.login({ clientId: clientVar })
});
```

The issue is the following: if I use debugging mode, it gives me errors when rendering the page as it is rendering with just node and not electron. If I run the script using terminal, which actually launches the script, everything seems to work with no errors, but when I click on the button with id '#set' it just doesn't do anything at all. No logs in console (its meant to log quite a few things) the rich presence doesn't work, its almost like the button hasn't been clicked at all. This issue persists with multiple methods I have tried, and nothing seemed to work yet. Please help <3

(I am using MacOS 12.0.1, Electron 16.0.7, and Node v16.13.2)

Comment: Instead of using `ipcRender.send()` and `ipcRender.on()` in your index.html `<script>` tag, have you tried [`ipcRender.invoke()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererinvokechannel-args)? That said, I don't understand the order of your `main.js` snippet. Are you trying to re-package the received data 'from' the render only to send it back **or** is the re-packaged data heading off to another script or rendered window? What is `client.request() meant to do? Adding some more explanation and possible code in your question may help us more to answer your question.

Comment: Can you show a snippet of your code where your window is created? Can you also show your `preload.js` script?